# Safari ios and ipad zooming in with camera

Tags: mobile-safari, getusermedia

Using the getUserMedia() API to use the camera.  The problem I have is that it works on everything but iOS and iPad.  I can snap a picture but I can't zoom.  I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625473/how-to-achieve-open-camera-and-zoom-in-out-facility-for-ios-safari-browser-using) but has no response.  I'm looking at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=getVideoTracks) and the [capabilities](https://caniuse.com/#search=MediaStreamTrack%20API%3A%20getCapabilities) and from what I can tell Safari on both mobile and desktop shows it's supported.  Any tips?

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoConstraints)
    .then(stream => {

        setTimeout((evt) => {

            const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            const capabilities = track.getCapabilities();
            const settings = track.getSettings();

            if (('zoom' in capabilities)) {

                alert('zoom exists');
                const elemZoom = this.dom.select(`${this.el} #zoom-slider`);

                // Map zoom to a slider element.
                elemZoom.min = capabilities[`zoom`][`min`];
                elemZoom.max = capabilities[`zoom`][`max`];
                elemZoom.step = capabilities[`zoom`][`step`];
                elemZoom.value = settings[`zoom`];
                elemZoom.oninput = (event) => {
                    track.applyConstraints({
                        advanced: [{
                            zoom: event.target.value
                        }]
                    });
                }
                elemZoom.hidden = false;
            }

            elemVideo.srcObject = stream;


        }, 500);
    })
    .catch(err => {

    });
}
```